# Fragment is not refreshing after button clicked in adapter-listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment, baseadapter

I have five tabs they are 1.home 2.menu 3.cart 4.account 5.more.Here cart tab consist of list view which is having the remove button in it,[image: my fragment]when i click on that remove button it must refresh the fragment itself so that it can load new data from the Json

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    @Bind(R.id.tabpager)
    ViewPager mViewpager;
    @Bind(R.id.tab_layout)
    TabLayout mTabs;
    private TabAdapter pageAdapter;
    String home,menu,cart,account,more;


    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initVariables(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        home= getString(R.string.home);
        menu = getString(R.string.menu);
        cart = getString(R.string.cart);
        account = getString(R.string.account);
        more = getString(R.string.more);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initData(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setupViewPager(mViewpager);
        setupTabLayout(mTabs);

    }



    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        pageAdapter = new TabAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getSupportFragmentManager());
        pageAdapter.addFragment(MainFragment.getInstance(home), home, R.drawable.home);
        pageAdapter.addFragment(MenuItems.getInstance(menu), menu, R.drawable.menu);
        pageAdapter.addFragment(Cart.getInstance(cart), cart, R.drawable.cart);
        pageAdapter.addFragment(Account.getInstance(account), account, R.drawable.account);
        pageAdapter.addFragment(More.getInstance(more), more, R.drawable.more);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Session cartsession=new Session(getApplicationContext());
                if (cartsession.isLoggedIn()){
                    if (position==2){
                        ((Cart) pageAdapter.getItem(position)).cartdata();
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    }



    public void setupTabLayout(TabLayout tabLayout) {
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewpager);

        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            tab.setCustomView(pageAdapter.getTabView(i));
        }
        tabLayout.requestFocus();
    }


}
```

TabAdapter.class

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    private List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Integer> mFragmentIcons = new ArrayList<>();




    public TabAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.mContext = context;
    }


    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title, int drawable) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        mFragmentIcons.add(drawable);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return mFragments.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        View tab = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.customtab, null);
        TextView tabText = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
        ImageView tabImage = (ImageView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tabImage);
        tabText.setText(mFragmentTitles.get(position));
        tabImage.setBackgroundResource(mFragmentIcons.get(position));
        if (position == 0) {
            tab.setSelected(true);
        }
        return tab;
    }
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Cart.Java

```
public class Cart extends Fragment {
    Button check_out;
    TextView subtotal;
    ListView cartview;
    CartAdapter cartAdapter;
    List<JSONParser> cartitems;
    SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;
    TextView cartstatus,cartempty;
    LinearLayout linearlay;
    RelativeLayout cartvisible;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View cartfrag = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart, container, false);
        subtotal = (TextView) cartfrag.findViewById(R.id.subtotal);
        cartview = (ListView) cartfrag.findViewById(R.id.cartview);
        cartstatus = (TextView) cartfrag.findViewById(R.id.cartstatus);
        cartempty = (TextView) cartfrag.findViewById(R.id.cartempty);
        linearlay = (LinearLayout) cartfrag.findViewById(R.id.linearlay);
        cartvisible = (RelativeLayout) cartfrag.findViewById(R.id.cartvisible);
        cartitems = new ArrayList<JSONParser>();
        cartAdapter = new CartAdapter(getActivity(), cartitems);
        cartview.setAdapter(cartAdapter);
        check_out = (Button) cartfrag.findViewById(R.id.check_out);
        check_out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent cart_check = new Intent(getActivity(), Check.class);
                startActivity(cart_check);
            }
        });
        Session cartlogged = new Session(getActivity());
        if (cartlogged.isLoggedIn()) {
            cartitems.clear();
            cartdata();
        } else {
            cartstatus.setText("Please Login");
        }
        return cartfrag;
    }

    void cartdata() {
        cartitems.clear();
        SharedPreferences customerid = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String customid = customerid.getString("customerid", "");
        String carturl = "http://standardtakeaway.co.uk/json/view_cart.php?userid=" + customid;
        Log.d("CartData", carturl);
        JsonObjectRequest cartreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, carturl, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    if (response.getString("status").equals("empty")) {
                        cartstatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        cartempty.setText("Your Cart is Empty");
                    } else {
                        JSONArray objarray = response.getJSONArray("items");
                        for (int i = 0; i < objarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject cartdataobj = objarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            linearlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            cartvisible.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            JSONParser parserdata = new JSONParser();
                            parserdata.setCartquantity(cartdataobj.getString("qty"));
                            parserdata.setCartbase(cartdataobj.getString("BaseName"));
                            parserdata.setCartprice(cartdataobj.getString("price"));
                            cartitems.add(parserdata);
                            loginPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();
                            JSONObject subobj = response.getJSONObject("details");
                            String subtext = subobj.getString("subtotal");
                            loginPrefsEditor.putString("Price", subtext);
                            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
                            subtotal.setText(subtext);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                cartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        cartreq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(6000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(cartreq);
    }

    public static Cart getInstance(String message) {
        Cart cart = new Cart();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("MSG", message);
        cart.setArguments(bundle);
        return cart;
    }
}
```

CartAdapter.class

```
public class CartAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    TextView quantity, basenamecart, cartprice;
    ImageButton delete;
    private List<JSONParser> cartitems;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    String removequantity, removeitemprice,removebasename;
    public CartAdapter(Context context, List<JSONParser> cartitems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cartitems = cartitems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cartitems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return cartitems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cartitems, parent, false);
            quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            basenamecart = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.basenamecart);
            cartprice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cartprice);
            delete= (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            final JSONParser dataparser = cartitems.get(position);
            quantity.setText(dataparser.getCartquantity());
            basenamecart.setText(dataparser.getCartbase());
            cartprice.setText(dataparser.getCartprice());
            delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    removequantity=dataparser.getCartquantity();
                    removebasename=dataparser.getCartbase();
                    removeitemprice=dataparser.getCartprice();
                    removecart();
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    private void removecart(){
        SharedPreferences customerid=context.getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String removeid=customerid.getString("customerid","");
        String removeurl="http://standardtakeaway.co.uk/json/del_cartitems.php?userid="+removeid+"&Item="+removebasename+"&price="+removeitemprice;
        Log.d("Remove",removeurl);
        final JsonArrayRequest removearray=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, removeurl, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                    Log.d("Remove", String.valueOf(response));
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        removearray.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(6000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(removearray);
    }

}
```

Comment: just remove item from `cartitems` and call  `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: but i need to refresh  it  from the base adapter of the list view located in that fragment Sir

Comment: call `notifyDataSetChanged ` after success `onResponse`

Comment: means in the adapter  class sir?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the concerned object from the list cartitems and then call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method to notify the any dependent views to refresh itself.

Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

Also, this is not the correct way to implement a BaseAdapter and handle changes in it. Maybe this will help : http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/

Also, try using the new RecyclerView in order to implement such things. It is available in the support library and definitely a good way to display collections and also makes it easy to add remove items with default animations too. Please read through it. A starting point http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Sir i just need to refresh the Cart Tab when button clicked from the list adapter

Comment: By Cart Tab you mean the ListView in the Cart Tab right, kishore jethava's answer seems to be correct, but still not the best way to implement in terms of software design.

Answer (score 0):

see **added line** and **updated line**.
add make sure only remove item from `list` if removed successfully from server.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cartitems, parent, false);
        quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        basenamecart = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.basenamecart);
        cartprice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cartprice);
        delete= (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        final JSONParser dataparser = cartitems.get(position);
        quantity.setText(dataparser.getCartquantity());
        basenamecart.setText(dataparser.getCartbase());
        cartprice.setText(dataparser.getCartprice());

        final int pos =position; // added line
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removequantity=dataparser.getCartquantity();
                removebasename=dataparser.getCartbase();
                removeitemprice=dataparser.getCartprice();
                removecart(pos); //updated line
            }
        });
    }
    return convertView;
}
public void updateCartitems(List<JSONParser> newCartitems) {
   cartitems.clear();
   cartitems.addAll(newCartitems);
   this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
private void removecart(int pos){ // updated line
    SharedPreferences customerid=context.getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String removeid=customerid.getString("customerid","");
    String removeurl="http://standardtakeaway.co.uk/json/del_cartitems.php?userid="+removeid+"&Item="+removebasename+"&price="+removeitemprice;
    Log.d("Remove",removeurl);
    final JsonArrayRequest removearray=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, removeurl, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                Log.d("Remove", String.valueOf(response));

            }

           cartitems.remove(pos); //added line
           updateCartitems(cartitems);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    removearray.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(6000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(removearray);
}
```

Comment: its removing successfully Sir if i refresh the page then only i can see the change sir till then i cant able to see the change

Comment: see edited answer. i have added method `updateCartitems`

Comment: Sir its removing the complete row but not refreshing tab if it dont refresh it the updated JSON data wont load sir